# Python find Element error for a drop down list

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

My Script takes me to a page where a table (with filters is present) This is the code for the header bar which I need to identify and use to export the table present on the page:

```
<td valign="top"><div class="menu-nav">
      <ul>
          <li><a href="window_data_columns_report.html" class="submodal-input2">
          <span class="icon-nav icon-columns"></span>
          Edit Columns</a></li>
         <li><a href="xxx" class="submodal-input2">
          <span id="id1" class="icon-nav icon-Task">
             </span>
          Task</a></li> <li>
                  </li>
        <li><a href="saveas" class="submodal-input2_1">
          <span class="icon-nav icon-save"></span>
          Save</a></li>
         <li id="export-menu"><a href="#">
          <span class="icon-nav icon-export"></span>
          Export</a>
          <ul class="sub">
             <li><a href="exportExcel.html?x" class="submodal-input2_3">Excel</a></li>
              <li><a href="exportCSV.html?x" class="submodal-input2_4">CSV</a></li>
          </ul>
          </li> 
      </ul>
    </div>
    </td>
```

I've tried:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='export-menu']/a/text()")))
            expbuttn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='export-menu']/a/text()")
            actions.move_to_element(expbuttn).perform()
            expbuttn.click()
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='export-menu']/ul/li[2]/a")))
            csvbuttn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='export-menu']/ul/li[2]/a")
            csvbuttn.click()
```

But no success.

The dropdown menu for the export options is only available when hovering or clicking on the first export button

any help?

Comment: What error is returned?

Comment: can you share full code or website?

Comment: please provide a link to this page